# Recommendations for dependencies in Service Layer

Tags: c#, architecture, domain-driven-design

What is recommended architectural approach for defining dependencies in a service class ?

Is this OK, when another class, ex. `OrderService` has dependencies to repository class ex. `CartRepository` instead of `CartService`? Should I always create one repository and one service per domain object ?

```
public class CartService : ICartService
{
    private IBuyerRepository _buyerRepository;
    private ICartRepository _cartRepository;
    private IConfigService _configService;  
    private ISimpleDataService _simpleDataService;

    public CartService(IBuyerRepository buyerRepository,
                       ICartRepository cartRepository,
                       IConfigService configService)
    {
        _buyerRepository = buyerRepository;
        _cartRepository = cartRepository;
        _configService = configService;
    }

    public void Save(Cart cart)
    {
        _cartRepository.Save(cart); 
    }
}
```

`OrderService` file:

```
public class OrderService : IOrderService
{
    public OrderService(ICartRepository cartRepository)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Domain services are there to orchestrate the interaction between repositories and domain objects. I wouldn't say it's a problem to use multiple dependencies in one domain service.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I was asking if all service layer classes should be depanded on approciate another domain object service class instead of repository class. In this example OrderService has dependecies to cartRepository, but wouldn't be better if instead that dependence I put there ICarService interface ?

Comment: Don't know if there is any explicit rule about this. I don't see any problems with using the cart repository in your order service. Otherwhise you would probably clutter your ICarService with methods that are only used from within other services.

Comment: But if I would like to check some validation logic (existing in Service class) before each saving object in database then maybe better approach could be inject service class in OrderService class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation is good as a first step, and in a simple, not too big, domain.

A such implementation has avantages:
While just one service per http resquest manages all the repositories it needs, there is no difficulty to manage the sql transaction to maintain integrity.

It has too disadvantages:
You could write two times, or more, the same business rules... We all are lazy so it's a problem. But a major failure will come when someone, or you, 6 months later, will call the repository for the third time in its service implementation and forget a business rule... bye bye lovely domain...

My recommendation would be that a service just call its repository, and calls the other services that encapsulate their own logic, when needed.
The only trick to remember is to propagate the transaction to avoid odd things to happen.

Hope it helps,
Julien